# Why doesn't void Main start after the if-condition?

Tags: c#

`Void Main` won't start again after the if-statement.

I have been experimenting for a while with such constructions and normally they work. But that's not the case. The generator void is somewhere below, please don't take it into consideration.

```
class Program
{
    private static string Input = Console.ReadLine();
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to start");
        Program.Generator();
        Console.WriteLine("Are you satisfied? Type '1' if yes or '2' if no.");
        Console.ReadLine();
        if (Input == "2")
                Program.Main();
    }
}
```

No errors, no mistakes, the console just closes after completing `Main`.

Comment: `Console.ReadLine();` should be `Input = Console.ReadLine();`

Comment: you will blow you stack someday :\

Comment: This is wrong on several levels, you should rethink your problem

Comment: And for your question, because the `Console.ReadLine();` just discards what user typed on keyboard, hence, variable `Input` contains what it has before `ReadLine`.

Comment: also _"generator void"_ sounds scary :| _"Abysmal void of the program generator"_ is a good title for a programming book

Comment: Commonly you do not recall `main()` within `main()`, my friend. You loop until the conditions are met so that the `main()` does not end. Recursion in this manner will cause you all sorts of headaches, as vasily.sib mentioned above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to stack overflow.  You're not crazy, just missing a piece of information about programming and flow of control.  Specifically, [iteration statements.](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Sharp_Programming/Control#Iteration_statements)

The program you've written will exit any time `Input` holds a value other than `2` because there's no loop forcing it to run over and over again.

```
static void Main()
{

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to start");
    Console.ReadKey();

    do
    {
        // Program.Generator();
        Console.WriteLine("Are you satisfied? Type '1' if yes or '2' if no.");

    } while (Console.ReadKey().KeyChar != '1');
}
```